# Animate a UISwitch on/off inside custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a UISwitch in a couple of custom UITableViewCells that aren't visually updating when I call `setOn:animated:` on them.

- I'm able to get/set the `on` value just fine.
- If I cause the table view to dequeue and redraw, the correct visual representation is shown.
- calling `reloadData` on the table view will update the switches abruptly (not what I want)
- tableView `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation` also updates the views with a crossfade from old to new (automatic row animations)
- `setNeedsLayout` and `setNeedsDisplay` doesn't seem to make any difference on the switch or superviews

What I want to do is call `[theSwitch setOn:onValue animated:YES];` and have the switch animate to the correct on/off position.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Adding code snippets...

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SwitchedCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[SettingsSwitchedTableCell alloc] init];
    }

    if([cell class] == [SettingsSwitchedTableCell class]){
                [[(SettingsSwitchedTableCell *)cell theSwitch] setOn: [[self.feedbackDS valueForRow:indexPath.row] boolValue]];
                [[(SettingsSwitchedTableCell *)cell theSwitch] addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            }
}
```

Reset Method (should set the switch back with animation, but a table reload required)

```
-(void)resetSettings {
    NSInteger rows = [self tableView:self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    for(NSInteger ii=0; ii<rows; ii++){
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:ii inSection:0]];
        if( [cell class] == [SettingsSwitchedTableCell class]){
            [[(SettingsSwitchedTableCell *)cell theSwitch] setOn:YES animated:YES];
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:ii inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you manage your cells? Should be rather easy to just get a cell at index path and set its switch's value to on or off.

Comment: Post the code showing how you get a reference to the cell and update the switch.

Comment: Post your custom cell code and show us how youre managing/drawing one cell including the uiswitch data. this problem of yours is quite easy to solve if you follow a few basic steps.

Comment: Updated. I thought it should be simple as well. It's been a while since I've done anything significant with custom table view cells, so I wouldn't be surprised if I'm missing something obvious. The above methods in my VC are a bit more complex, but here you get the relevant gist.